# Const Multidimensional array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, global-variables, constants

In C, how would I add the const modifier (or any other modifier) to a global multidimensional array so that both the variable and the values it holds are constant.

For example how would I add a const modifier to this:

```
byte fruitIds[][2] = { { 0x01, 0x02}, {0x02, 0x03} }
```

so that at the end of the assignment you can't do this:

```
fruitIds = vegetableIds;
```

or this:

```
fruitIds[0] = {0x02, 0x03};
```

or this:

```
fruitIds[0][0] = 0x02;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Arrays are already non-modifiable lvalues.  That just means you need to make the values `const`:

```
const byte fruitIds[][2] = { { 0x01, 0x02}, { 0x02, 0x03} };
```

These assignments from your post:

```
fruitIds = vegetableIds;
fruitIds[0] = {0x02, 0x03};
```

Are already illegal.  The latter isn't even valid syntax, but I get a `read-only variable is not assignable` message from `clang` trying to do the former.